# allow appeals for false and slanderous rejections

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

How can one appeal false claims in edit rejections? What I mean, why I ask:

I attempted an [edit to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15169556/915044), seeking to

```
update (e.g., Exuberant -> Universal), add links, improve usage
```

My edit [was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13885972). That would not itself be a problem, except that 2 of the rejecters ([Al Foиce ѫ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3219606/al-fo%d0%b8ce-%d1%ab) and [Morten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/619546/morten)) rejected the edit on the grounds that it

```
defaces the post in order to promote a product or service,
or is deliberately destructive
```

This is completely false, not to mention slanderous. I updated the post to

1. note that Exuberant Ctags is inactive: see [its website](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/).
2. note that Universal Ctags is ECtags' successor, as noted by [UCtags itself](https://ctags.io/)

   ```
   Github exuberant-ctags repository was started by Reza Jelveh
   and was later moved to the universal-ctags organization.
   ```

   and by [ECtags' Project Activity](https://sourceforge.net/p/ctags/activity/?page=0&limit=100#57807cc4e88f3d6d9df125d6) (where the activity is ~all merges from UCtags).
3. add explanatory links. One may claim (as [Black Moses](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5405086/black-moses) did) that this `actively harm[s] readability`. IMHO this claim is absurd--one can simply not click on the link--but at least the claim is more subjective and **much** less defamatory. By contrast, adding germane, non-spam links (as all of mine were--[examine the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13885972)) **in no way** supports the claim that my edit seeks to `promote a product or service`, much less the claim that I sought to be `deliberately destructive` to the original answer.

The claims of [Al Foиce ѫ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3219606/al-fo%d0%b8ce-%d1%ab) and [Morten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/619546/morten) are at best misleading, and at worst malfeasance. How to clear their slurs from my edit record?

Comment: You completely rewrote the entire answer in your own words. It bares almost no resemblance to the original. So I too would have rejected it, but probably not for the same reasons that you're complaining about. Also, those users are not moderators.

Comment: On first and second glance, you totally rewrote the answer, adding tons of links. Very few people bother to have a third glance.

Comment: I added links, and noted the issues above. This is clear from [the diff](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13885972). How does that support the claims that `This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive`?

Comment: Please stop pretending like an incorrect rejection reason is some great injustice against you, because it's not and it only makes other people not want to take your question seriously. I would suggest removing all the references to slander and defamation, and focusing your question on why those users thought your edit was defacing the post and what you could have done better. Otherwise, this discussion is going nowhere.

Comment: @Mysticial: `[your edit] bares almost no resemblance to the original.` Completely false, as is clear from [the diff](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13885972).

Comment: @animuson: I **am** `focusing my question on why those users thought your edit was defacing the post`. Their claims are false, I'm making that point. Users should have a way to remove false claims from their record.

Comment: @TomRoche no they should not, same way we should not rewrite history. (real life history.)

Comment: So you're gonna insult us too? -1 from me. That diff you have is the very definition of rewriting the entire thing.

Comment: @TomRoche No you're not. You're making your own false claims about the situation and making demands that are completely unnecessary. No one slandered you. No one defamed you. Some users rejected your edit for a loosely related reason and you're overreacting to it.

Comment: @Mysticial and @animuson: 'Al Foиce ѫ' and 'Morten' claimed that my edit [`defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive`](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13885972). That is false, and your rebuttals fail to obscure that fact.

Comment: @TomRoche Since you're claiming slander, then obviously you have proof that these users knew that the claims they were making was false when they made them, and that they did so with the expressed *intent* of harming your reputation.  Please present said evidence to support your accusation.

Comment: Just FYI, you've damaged your reputation *far, far* more with your behavior in this meta question than it was damaged as a result of an edit of yours being rejected.  The irony of you *severely* damaging your reputation in an attempt to "rectify" your damaged reputation is...rather entertaining.

Comment: @Servy: your claim is false. A claim is slanderous if it is [`a false statement that harms the reputation of an individual`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defamation)--no intent required. 'Al Foиce ѫ' and 'Morten' made the claim, it's their responsibility to support it.

Comment: Wikipedia is generally not a good source of definitive information, especially about legal matters. But we're not here to argue about the law. Since you refuse to change your question, I'll just decline your request because we have no intention of adding this.

Comment: @TomRoche To add to animuson's point, you should really read past the first sentence of the article if you want to cite it as your argument, considering it goes on to discuss in the details how malicious intent *is* an element, and how as long as the person making the claim has a reasonable belief that the claim is true the actual correctness of the claim doesn't matter.

Comment: @TomRoche *"defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive"* is a prepared message for the reject option *"spam **or vandalism**"* and rewriting an entire answer can be seen as vandalism

Comment: Edits can be rejected on any SE site, closing it as "belongs to specific site" is totally wrong.

Answer (score 8):

You can't appeal a rejected edit or remove it from your history, unless the post itself get deleted.

In this specific case, you made a mistake. You completely rewrote the answer, adding bunch of links that on first glance might appear as spam.

In those cases, simply post a new answer, it's simple as that.

Instead of trying to call out those who help keep the site organised, learn from your mistake, there's really nothing so bad in having this in your history. Very few will see it anyway, and on closer inspection it's clear you didn't really spam.

Comment: `You completely rewrote the answer`: false, see [the diff](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13885972). `adding bunch of links that on first glance might appear as spam`: well that's the point, 'Al Foиce ѫ' and 'Morten' should have taken more care before making false claims, and defamed users should have a way to correct the record.

Comment: (1) I have made a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39905971/915044), thanks for the suggestion. (2) `on closer inspection it's clear you didn't really spam` Then why should those comments be allowed to stand? Hence my post: defamed users should have a means to appeal, and malicious rejecters should have *that* on *their* edit record.

Comment: @TomRoche The diff *does* in fact make it clear that you completely re-wrote it.  What about it makes you think that you didn't?

Comment: @TomRoche I saw the diff. It's clear as crystal that you totally rewrote the whole answer. As for "correcting the record", there's nothing to correct. Like I said, you are the one making mistake, the rejection was valid. Maybe not as spam, but it's not that important.

Comment: @Servy: (1) You fail to address the defamatory claim that my edit `defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive` which was then and is now false. (2) The structure and function of [shigio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15169556/915044) and my edit (now [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39905971/915044)) are the same, hence your claim is false.

Comment: @shadow-wizard: `the rejection was valid. Maybe not as spam` misses the point. If Al Foиce ѫ and Morten had wanted to reject it (as Black Moses did) on readability grounds, **that** would have been valid. But rejecting the edit by claiming that it `defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive` is invalid.

Comment: @TomRoche 1) Indeed, I didn't address that claim in my comment.  Shadow, and others, have covered it adequately. 2) The fact that the overall structure is similar does not mean that you didn't rewrite the answer.  The answer, after the edit, is a completely different answer, with completely different meaning, completely different facts, presentation, pretty much everything.  That's rewriting an answer.